# Python Sorted, Not Sorting Data

Tags: python, list, sorting, input

I have a very simple program to sort data and write it to a text file, but the sorted method is not doing what it should be. Instead the values are entering the array and text file in the order I input them. Can anyone quickly explain why?

```
import os
import os.path

values = []
#for value in values:
data = 1

while data:

    data = input('Enter the values. Press enter to confirm values:')

    if data:
        values.append(data)
    else:
        data = data
        print(sorted(values))
sort = sorted(values)
print(sort)

name = open("sortedvalues.txt", "a+") #opens file usernames.txt and gets ready to write to it
file = str(sort) #converts the values to a string and writes them to the file
name.write('\n' + file) #writes contents in file to usernames.txt
name.close() #closes file
open1 = open("sortedvalues.txt", "r") #opens file to read it
print('reading')
print (open1.read()) #prints whatever is in the text file
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In particular, we should not have to create our own test case and hand-enter data.  I took the trouble to do this as a break, and I cannot reproduce your problem.  I get the input in collating sequence -- sorted as expected.

Comment: Just from the first sight: expression `data = data` is redundant.

Comment: When do you plan to break from infinite `while` loop? As it stands, this goes on taking values from user.

Comment: @Austin: the loop will break on a null entry, as the input prompt suggests.

Comment: @Austin It will break when `data` is an empty string, i.e. when the user just presses Enter.

Comment: You are opening the file in `a+` mode, so if you run this program twice, the second batch of input will be appended to the existing contents.  Perhaps you're misinterpreting this as the input not being sorted?

Comment: Can you post the example of values you are trying to sort? As I am unable to recreate the issue

Comment: Even with the code added by @emre I am still having sorting issues. As an example I entered `4 55 64 344` and the returned and data in the file was `['344', '4', '55', '64']` . Interestingly enough it works with small values so I think the issue has to do with the data type. Using `3 5 4 2 1` as inputs the program returns the array `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` .

Comment: @JohnGordon like the above comment says, the loop breaks on user input. I am sure this is horrible practice, but as someone learning Python still I wanted a quick approach to stopping data entry on user input.

Comment: @AndrejKesely `data = data` is what I am using to break the loop. Without it, on a null entry the program keeps data as true and the loop does not break.

Answer (score 0):

I could not recreate your issue. The below code is works fine, sorts the given bunch of numbers correctly and writes to file.

Also you are sorting array twice, I just corrected it.

```
values = []
sorted_values = []
data = 1

while data:
    data = input('Enter the values. Press enter to confirm values:')

    if data:
        values.append(data)
    else:
        data = data
        # here you are sorted it first and second outside of while loop
        sorted_values = sorted(values)
        print(sorted_values)

print(sorted_values)

with open("sortedvalues.txt", "a+") as name:
    name.write('\n' + str(sorted_values))

with open("sortedvalues.txt", "r") as open1:
    print('reading')
    print (open1.read())
```

inputs:

```
5
3
4
2
1
0
```

inside file:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I said this above, but when I use other more random values and values >9 the sorting seems to behave oddly. I'm sure this has to do with some basic syntax of the `sort()` method that I am missing, but I am still not sure what that is and how to fix it to accept values of any size.

Comment: Can you provide exact input & output and expected output?

Comment: Yes, As an example I entered `4 55 64 344` and the returned and data in the file was `['344', '4', '55', '64']` . I would expect the returned array to be [ '4', '55', '64', '344']` .

Comment: @BenjaminPharris `['344', '4', '55', '64']` is indeed sorted, given that those values are strings.  If you want numeric sorting, you'll have to convert the input values.

Comment: @JohnGordon this is absolutely the answer. I had a feeling it was some trivial formatting issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnGordon answered the question in a below comment. The issue was not with the way the code was working, as improper as it may be. The problem is that the integer values are actually being taken as strings and sorting as if they were strings. The input values first need to be converted before being sorted.

**Edit** I should add that specifying the input as an integer results in a traceback because null (when the user presses enter to confirm the entered values) can not be parsed as an integer. To work around this, I simply added

```
while data:

data = input('Enter the values. Press enter to confirm values:')

if data:
        values.append(int(data))
else:
    data = data
    print(sorted(values))
```

Specifically, in the `if data:`portion, specifying to append data as an int to the list solves the problem and the `sorted` or `.sort()` methods work correctly.